# Blur out an image then back to normal state

Tags: css, transition, blur

I'm seeing if there is a way to blur out your background for a few seconds then have it come into view. I was trying to play around with the blur attribute and the transition attribute but I was not getting the results I was getting. I tried something like this on my css

```
body{
    background:black;
        -webkit-filter: blur(10px);

}
.body{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:95%;`enter code here`
    clear:both;
        transition:body 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you don't have a class named `"body"` so the period in your second selector is an error. Also, you have the syntax wrong for `transition`. The first value is the property to transition, not a selector. And, depending on the level of support you require, you need vendor prefixes on both the transition property and the property being transitioned, e.g.

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

BTW, I'm not sure if `-filter` is an animatable property.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/sHL9m/3/

1) Use `all` in the `transition`
2) Despite what the `prefixes` lead you to believe, this didn't work in all browsers
3) But it did work the same for `backgrounds` and `img`

I change a class using `javascript`, `css` handles the rest.

```
.filter {
  filter:blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(10px);
  -moz-filter:blur(10px);
  -o-filter:blur(10px);
  -ms-filter:blur(10px);

  -webkit-transition: all 5.0s linear 1.0s;
  -moz-transition: all 5.0s linear 1.0s;
  -ms-transition: all 5.0s linear 1.0s;
  -o-transition: all 5.0s linear 1.0s;
  transition: all 5.0s linear 1.0s;
}
.filter.animae {
   filter:blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter:blur(0px);
  -moz-filter:blur(0px);
  -o-filter:blur(0px);
  -ms-filter:blur(0px);
}
.bg {
    display:inline-block;
    width:360px;
    height:424px;
    background:url(http://gruntjs.com/img/grunt-logo.svg);
}
```

Comment: This fiddle follows your directions: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/sHL9m/4/ Works great in Chrome...